# Android firebase auth state listener called multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase android sdk v.9.0.2 and can't get past the registration for now. I am adding an auth state listener and removing it on successful registration. Yet it is called multiple times. This is what i'm getting in my logs:

```
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
D/ActivityRegister: auth listener called
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( bwVX8jBbZvYcIj28hYsGZCcbzxi1 ).
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
D/ActivityRegister: auth listener called
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( bwVX8jBbZvYcIj28hYsGZCcbzxi1 ).
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
```

The "D/ActivityRegister: auth listener called" log is inside the listener iteself. As you can see, when Firebase notifies 0 listeners, it is actually called. And when it shows 1 listener, the listener doesn't get called at all.
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I have the same problem and didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: I have just asked for help from technical supports of Firebase and waiting for any help. If any received, I would share with you.

Comment: I got an email from technical support of Firebase. They say already know about this issue and we have to wait for a bugfix.

Comment: thank you. for now i'm removing the listeners when not needed as a workaround to trigger other code and re-add the listeners when that code fails.

Comment: Having the same issue. Waiting for a fix.

Comment: any updates for this issue ?

Comment: it seems that it's a 'feature', so you have to use workarounds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixes are not expected. That closed issue.
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/80

Answer (score 1):

You can find when this method is triggered here:

[Firebase Reference - AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)

I handle this function trigger with an `switch` and only use the *"Login_Attempt"* and *"Register_Attempt"* (to send verification email) cases ignoring the rest of them. Just create a `String` variable (and i.e. when user clics Sign_In button, set it as *"Login_Attempt"*)

BR